# I want to target multiple divs inside a parent div

Tags: html, css, target

I have created a hexagon from 3 divs combined. I want to hover over the hexagon and all 3 divs to change colour.

```
<div class="hex" >
 <div class="left"  ></div>
   <div class="middle"  ></div>
  <div class="right"  ></div>
  </div>  




.hex {
    float: left;
    margin-right: -26px;
    margin-bottom: -50px;
    }

.hex .left {
    float: left;
    width: 0;
    border-right: 60px solid #6C6;
    border-top: 104px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 104px solid transparent;
}

.hex .left:hover {
     border-right: 60px solid yellow; 
     }

.hex .middle {
    float: left;
    width: 124px;
    height: 208px;
    background: #6C6;
}

.hex .middle:hover {
background-color: yellow; 
 }

.hex .right {
    float: left;
    width: 0;
    border-left: 60px solid #6C6;
    border-top: 104px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 104px solid transparent;
}


.hex .right:hover {
border-left:60px solid yellow; 
 }
```

As you can see, at the moment I am only able to target each element of the hexagon but not the hexagon as a whole.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying but I think its not possible with pure html/css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS can not associate and combine the `:hover` state of separated individual elements.

In this case, you can associate a `:hover` state to the whole `.hex` element in each selector. After a `:hover`, you can add more subselectors:

```
.hex:hover .left
```

(instead of <strike>`.hex .left:hover`</strike>)

The full code:

```css
.hex {
    float: left;
    margin-right: -26px;
    margin-bottom: -50px;
}

.hex .left {
    float: left;
    width: 0;
    border-right: 60px solid #6C6;
    border-top: 104px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 104px solid transparent;
}

.hex:hover .left {
    border-right: 60px solid yellow; /* or simply: border-right-color: yellow; */
}

.hex .middle {
    float: left;
    width: 124px;
    height: 208px;
    background: #6C6;
}

.hex:hover .middle {
    background-color: yellow; 
}

.hex .right {
    float: left;
    width: 0;
    border-left: 60px solid #6C6;
    border-top: 104px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 104px solid transparent;
}


.hex:hover .right {
    border-left: 60px solid yellow; /* or simply: border-left-color: yellow; */
}
```

```html
<div class="hex">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="middle"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.hex:hover div { }` maybe? I don't think that will work in some older version of IE though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [currentcolor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value)

```css
.hex {
    float: left;
    margin-right: -26px;
    margin-bottom: -50px;
    color:#6C6;
    }

.hex .left {
    float: left;
    width: 0;
    border-right: 60px solid currentcolor;
    border-top: 104px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 104px solid transparent;
}


.hex .middle {
    float: left;
    width: 124px;
    height: 208px;
    background: currentcolor;
}

.hex .right {
    float: left;
    width: 0;
    border-left: 60px solid currentcolor;
    border-top: 104px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 104px solid transparent;
}


.hex:hover .right{
border-left-color:yellow; 
 }
.hex:hover .left{
border-right-color:yellow; 
 }
.hex:hover .middle{
   color:yellow; 
 }
```

```html
<div class="hex" >
     <div class="left" ></div>
     <div class="middle" ></div>
     <div class="right" ></div>
</div>
```

or use [pseudo elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements)

```css
.hex {
    width:125px;
    height:208px;
    position:relative;
    background-color:#6C6;
    margin:20px auto
    }
.hex:before,.hex:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    width: 0;
    height:0
}
.hex:before {
    left:-60px;
    border-right: 60px solid #6C6;
    border-top: 104px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 104px solid transparent;
}
.hex:after {
    right:-60px;
    border-left: 60px solid #6C6;
    border-top: 104px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 104px solid transparent;
}

.hex:hover{
   background-color:yellow; 
 }
.hex:hover:before{
   color:yellow; 
   border-right-color:yellow; 
 }
.hex:hover:after{
   border-left-color:yellow; 
 }
```

```html
<div class="hex" ></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
 .hex{transition:875ms ease all;}
  .hex:hover div{
    background:red;
    }
```